# creating dropdownlist from ViewData

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Does anyone have any idea why the code below doesn't give me any value but instead gives me "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem"?

If I don't do a `foreach` but instead substitute the `ViewData` with this

`<%= Html.DropDownList("PersonOnCallCheckBoxList") %>`, I get the correct value. Please help.

```
foreach (var person in ViewData["Person"] as IEnumerable)
{
%>
   <input type="checkbox" value="<%= person %>" /><%= person %><br />
<%
}
```

Comment: did you want a set of checkboxes, or a dropdownlist for your Persons?

Comment: Ok, never mind I've figured it out. Thank you guys all for helping.

Comment: consider leaving the solution or remedy for others, as they may find themselves in the same situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          <%
            var list = this.ViewData["Persons"] as SelectList;

            foreach (var person in list)
            {
              %>
                  <input id="cbPerson" type="checkbox" value="<%= person.Value %>" />
                  <label for="cbPersonOnCall"><%= person.Text %></label><br />
              <%
            }
          %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because person is a SelectListItem.

use `person.Text` to get the displayed text and `person.Value` to get the backing value

Html.DropDownList is built for working with SelectListItems so it does the right thing, but if you are manually working with the Items you'll have to get the Value and Text yourself.